# Where in the database are content type fields stored in Drupal 6

Tags: php, sql, drupal-6, drupal-7

I need to access particular fields of a content type so that I can sort and display what I want accordingly. I do not have the Views module available because I do not have installation permissions, so I have to do this with a query and some php magic.

I received some very helpful information about the table names of fields for Drupal 7, but it appears that the organization/conventions for field values and where they are stored has changed since 6.

I found out in Drupal 7 that each content type field is stored in its own separate table. Assuming I had a field which I called group, the table name would be "field_data_field_group."

However, when I attempt to use this convention on my Drupal 6 site, it says this table does not exist.

My question is what is the name of the table fields are stored in? Or is it a completely different system than Drupal 7? Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I don't know much about Drupal, but isn't it a web framework, and not a database?  What RDBMS are you using for your back-end database?  SQLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Drupal 6, look in the following couple of places:

1. In the Drupal 6 database, look for a table that's called **content_[your_field_name]**, for example, content_field_brief_description.  Do a SELECT * to see what rows you have for that field table, if it exists.
2. Look for a table called **content_type_[your_content_type]**, for example content_type_resource.  Do the same with that table and see if you get any columns in that one for fields, other than the title/body that may be associated with that content type.

Let us know if that worked!

---

Edit:

Sample code:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {table_name}");
while ($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {
   // do something like drupal_set_message(var_dump($row));
}
```

Keep the curly brackets as are, but just replace that with the table name you're using at the moment...

Comment: I'm getting an error looking for content_[your_field_name] (in my case it's "content_field_group"). I am able to query content_type_person per your 2nd recommendation. However, I have been unsuccessful in using a SELECT * to find the row labels so I can see what I'm working with.

Comment: You know, unfortunately, I don't work much in Drupal 6 anymore, so I've forgotten some of the syntax, but look at my edited response above to see an example to at least get you started.   I mostly look at my tables using phpMyAdmin, but I'm assuming you don't have access to that or something like that.  Let me know if the above gets you in the right track or Accept the response if it resolves your issue!

Comment: Using the table "content_type_[your type here]" and your provided code above, each field of every instance of the provided content type was displayed. From there, I was able to figure it out. My long standing problem has been solved. Thanks a ton.